# Snowflake Where Clause Not Filtering?

Tags: sql, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running this query in snowflake:

```
select *
from my_database.information_schema.tables
where
    table_schema NOT LIKE '%information%';
```

When I look at the records, some of them have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` as the `table_schema.`

Why is my filter not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/like.html) is case sensitive, where-as [ILIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ilike.html) is case insensitive. And your two strings are different cases. So I suggest you swap to ILIKE

```
SELECT 'a' LIKE 'A' as "a_like_A", 'a' ILIKE 'A' as "a_ilike_A";
```

gives:

```
a_like_A    a_ilike_A
FALSE       TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

> *When I look at the records, some of them have INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the table_schema.*

> [Identifiers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html)
>
> When an identifier is unquoted, **it is stored and resolved in uppercase.**

The issue is you are comparing uppercase vs lowercase string which are different.

```
where table_schema LIKE '%information%';  -- this comparison will not work
```

Other way to compare:

```
where table_schema LIKE UPPER('%information%');
```

---

It is worth noting that `SHOW TABLES LIKE '<patern>'` is case-insensitive by design, and will return a match for the following regardless of version used:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%information%';
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%INFORMATION%';
SHOW TABLES LIKE '%Information%';
```